# Fedex SOAP Request Failing

Tags: soap, fedex

I am looking for the reason why the below request is failing to retrieve information. This is copied from the Fedex developer website and it doesn't work. When my program hits the GetRates line it throws a could not connect to host exception. I tried adding the connection_timeout and setting the default_timeout in php and neither appear to work. I contacted the Fedex dev team and they are receiving my post successfully I am just not able to get any response besides the fault. Has anyone had experience with Fedex or know what might cause this to be failing?

I am posting my current code below. I am using PHP7 on an AS400 machine using Zendserver.

```
<?php
// Copyright 2009, FedEx Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Version 12.0.0

require_once('../library/fedex-common.php5');

$newline = "<br />";
//The WSDL is not included with the sample code.
//Please include and reference in $path_to_wsdl variable.
$path_to_wsdl = "../wsdl/RateService_v24.wsdl"; 

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);
$client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1, 'connection_timeout' => 30)); // Refer to    http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.soap.php for more information

$request['WebAuthenticationDetail'] = array(
'ParentCredential' => array(
    'Key' => getProperty('parentkey'),
    'Password' => getProperty('parentpassword')
),
'UserCredential' => array(
    'Key' => getProperty('key'), 
    'Password' => getProperty('password')
)
); 
$request['ClientDetail'] = array(
'AccountNumber' => getProperty('shipaccount'), 
'MeterNumber' => getProperty('meter')
);
$request['TransactionDetail'] = array('CustomerTransactionId' => ' *** Rate Request using PHP ***');
$request['Version'] = array(
'ServiceId' => 'crs', 
'Major' => '24', 
'Intermediate' => '0', 
'Minor' => '0'
);
$request['ReturnTransitAndCommit'] = true;
$request['RequestedShipment']['DropoffType'] = 'REGULAR_PICKUP'; // valid values REGULAR_PICKUP, REQUEST_COURIER, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['ShipTimestamp'] = date('c');
$request['RequestedShipment']['ServiceType'] = 'INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY'; // valid values STANDARD_OVERNIGHT, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, FEDEX_GROUND, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackagingType'] = 'YOUR_PACKAGING'; // valid values FEDEX_BOX, FEDEX_PAK, FEDEX_TUBE, YOUR_PACKAGING, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['TotalInsuredValue']=array(
'Ammount'=>100,
'Currency'=>'USD'
);
$request['RequestedShipment']['Shipper'] = addShipper();
$request['RequestedShipment']['Recipient'] = addRecipient();
$request['RequestedShipment']['ShippingChargesPayment'] = addShippingChargesPayment();
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackageCount'] = '1';
$request['RequestedShipment']['RequestedPackageLineItems'] = addPackageLineItem1();



try {
if(setEndpoint('changeEndpoint')){
    $newLocation = $client->__setLocation(setEndpoint('endpoint'));
}

$response = $client -> getRates($request);

if ($response -> HighestSeverity != 'FAILURE' && $response -> HighestSeverity != 'ERROR'){      
    $rateReply = $response -> RateReplyDetails;
    echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '<tr><td>Service Type</td><td>Amount</td><td>Delivery Date</td></tr><tr>';
    $serviceType = '<td>'.$rateReply -> ServiceType . '</td>';
    if($rateReply->RatedShipmentDetails && is_array($rateReply->RatedShipmentDetails)){
        $amount = '<td>$' . number_format($rateReply->RatedShipmentDetails[0]->ShipmentRateDetail->TotalNetCharge->Amount,2,".",",") . '</td>';
    }elseif($rateReply->RatedShipmentDetails && ! is_array($rateReply->RatedShipmentDetails)){
        $amount = '<td>$' . number_format($rateReply->RatedShipmentDetails->ShipmentRateDetail->TotalNetCharge->Amount,2,".",",") . '</td>';
    }
    if(array_key_exists('DeliveryTimestamp',$rateReply)){
        $deliveryDate= '<td>' . $rateReply->DeliveryTimestamp . '</td>';
    }else if(array_key_exists('TransitTime',$rateReply)){
        $deliveryDate= '<td>' . $rateReply->TransitTime . '</td>';
    }else {
        $deliveryDate='<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    }
    echo $serviceType . $amount. $deliveryDate;
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';

    printSuccess($client, $response);
}else{
    printError($client, $response);
} 
writeToLog($client);    // Write to log file   
} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
   printFault($exception, $client);        
}



function addShipper(){
$shipper = array(
    'Contact' => array(
        'PersonName' => 'Sender Name',
        'CompanyName' => 'Sender Company Name',
        'PhoneNumber' => '9012638716'
    ),
    'Address' => array(
        'StreetLines' => array('Address Line 1'),
        'City' => 'Collierville',
        'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'TN',
        'PostalCode' => '38017',
        'CountryCode' => 'US'
    )
);
return $shipper;
}
function addRecipient(){
$recipient = array(
    'Contact' => array(
        'PersonName' => 'Recipient Name',
        'CompanyName' => 'Company Name',
        'PhoneNumber' => '9012637906'
    ),
    'Address' => array(
        'StreetLines' => array('Address Line 1'),
        'City' => 'Richmond',
        'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'BC',
        'PostalCode' => 'V7C4V4',
        'CountryCode' => 'CA',
        'Residential' => false
    )
);
return $recipient;                                      
}
function addShippingChargesPayment(){
$shippingChargesPayment = array(
    'PaymentType' => 'SENDER', // valid values RECIPIENT, SENDER and THIRD_PARTY
    'Payor' => array(
        'ResponsibleParty' => array(
            'AccountNumber' => getProperty('billaccount'),
            'CountryCode' => 'US'
        )
    )
);
return $shippingChargesPayment;
}
function addLabelSpecification(){
$labelSpecification = array(
    'LabelFormatType' => 'COMMON2D', // valid values COMMON2D, LABEL_DATA_ONLY
    'ImageType' => 'PDF',  // valid values DPL, EPL2, PDF, ZPLII and PNG
    'LabelStockType' => 'PAPER_7X4.75'
);
return $labelSpecification;
}
function addSpecialServices(){
$specialServices = array(
    'SpecialServiceTypes' => array('COD'),
    'CodDetail' => array(
        'CodCollectionAmount' => array(
            'Currency' => 'USD', 
            'Amount' => 150
        ),
        'CollectionType' => 'ANY' // ANY, GUARANTEED_FUNDS
    )
);
return $specialServices; 
}
function addPackageLineItem1(){
$packageLineItem = array(
    'SequenceNumber'=>1,
    'GroupPackageCount'=>1,
    'Weight' => array(
        'Value' => 50.0,
        'Units' => 'LB'
    ),
    'Dimensions' => array(
        'Length' => 108,
        'Width' => 5,
        'Height' => 5,
        'Units' => 'IN'
    )
);
return $packageLineItem;
}
?>
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Both test and live endpoints return `Could not connect to host` when executing the sample code from FedEx. Anybody who has an idea?

Comment: Please check on this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53960024/does-fedex-provide-discounted-shipment-rates